# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to generate sitemap automatically by using a sitemap_generator gem. I tried to add `show` action since I started getting an error. It was originally empty..

Following is my **posts controller**:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :create, :destroy]
  before_filter :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(9)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.rss { render :layout =>false }
    end
  end

  def show
    @posts = Post.all

  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "#{@post.title} Updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_url, notice: "#{@post.title} Deleted"
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,  :contents, :author_id, :approved, :summary, :preview_image_id, :category, :social_title, :blog_title)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])

    # If an old id or a numeric id was used to find the record, then
    # the request path will not match the post_path, and we should do
    # a 301 redirect that uses the current friendly id.
    if params[:action] == 'show' && request.path != post_path(@post)
      return redirect_to @post, :status => :moved_permanently
    end
  end



end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: "home#index"
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end  
end
```

**sitemap.rb**

```
Post.friendly.find_each do |post|
    add post_url(post), :lastmod => post.created_at
  end
```

I tried both with 'friendly' and without 'friendly'.

and When I run `rake sitemap:refresh`  I receive the following error
ubuntu:~/environment/site (master) $ rake sitemap:refresh

```
In '/home/ubuntu/environment/site/public/':
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
rake aborted!
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Post id: 1, title: "4 Tips For Managing Your Maintenance Team", contents: "<p>Maintenance teams are a special kind of problem...", approved: nil, created_at: "2020-03-30 16:17:28", updated_at: "2020-05-04 17:07:30", url: nil, blog_title: "4 Tips For Managing Your Maintenance Team">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: You don't need to use `friendly` here it all. Its only needed when you want to use FriendlyId to look up records based on a slug which is something you would only do in a controller. The error itself is kind of bizarre - there is nothing in your routes which explains why the helper is not treating the first argument as the id. You might want use `method(:post_url)` to inspect the method and see if its being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: @max Thanks for the comment.

I removed `friendly` and tried again but no luck.

Do you mean if `method(:post_url)` is defined as duplicate in the other rb files? Then, no. I just double-checked.

Comment: Yes exactly. What happens if you explicitly pass the key as `post_url(id: post.to_param)`?

Comment: @max Thanks!!

`Post.find_each do |post|
    add post_path(id: post.to_param), :lastmod => post.created_at
  end `  

with the above modified line, I could successfully generate a sitemap.
I would appreciate if you can elaborate a bit more on the `post_url(id: post.to_param)`

I don't understand :(

Comment: You can either pass the arguments to the url helpers as positional arguments or as a hash. Your app should be treating the positional argument as the id but I have absolutely no clue why its treating it as the locale - maybe a strange localization gem or something? Its nothing I have ever seen before.